# Android using LocalBroadcastManager when MainActivity closed

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a service that is activated when alarm is activated. It extends IntentService, and in that service I need to send a message to MainActivity. The MainActivity on receiving this message then performs some necessary work. I send the message to MainActivity using :

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This works OK if the MainActivity is currently active (displayed). If however the MainActivity is not currently active, I create it using :

```
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        mPendingIntent.send(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
```

If the MainActivity is currently active (displayed), then the message reaches it. However, when I have to re-create the MainActivity using a PendingIntent, the message sent via LocalBroadcastManager does not reach the MainActivity. If I sleep for eg. 2000ms, before sending the message (where the MainActivity has to be recreated), the message does reach the MainActivity.

While this may be understandable, I would prefer to use a fail-safe way of ensuring that the app works as intended.

To guarantee that the MainActivity has received the message, do I need to send a message from the MainActivity to the service to verify that the message has been received?

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way to handle this?

Only use `LocalBroadcastManager` when the activity already exists. If you have to start the activity, include the information that you would have sent in the broadcast in the `Intent` that you use to start the activity. The activity can then look for that information in `onCreate()` and use it; otherwise, it can behave normally.